# Can't Add testers in TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I added a person in iTunesConnect (User and Roles) with the role as developer.

After he accepted the invitation, he is ready to be added to test the build. 
I could add the user to my particular app build. 
Then I tried sending an invitation to him. But the status of the user is "-".

Please refer the screen shot.

[image: Why the 1st person status as "-"? He also didn't get invitation]

Earlier I could add number of testers, but why am I getting a problem only with this user?

Comment: The status is showing "-" but he received invitation also he can able to install application too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the user, re-add him and Resend the invitation. It always works in my case.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know It is not working for particular account. I tried many times. finally it is work. Thank you